# Insert Code in LyX

Tags: ide, latex, lyx

does anybody know how to insert code into lyx? just like what is available here?
I want to have a code like  `this` .

Comment: Can you do a bit more explaining what you already tried, and what you want to use it for.

Comment: I just tried to change the font. I was wondering if there are template styles like "toggle noun" and "toggle emph"

Comment: It's a bit annoying when a question that precisely matches what I am looking for is marked off topic. Lyx is a tool that is used by some programmers when preparing documentation for projects. Unless the question itself is flawed, it's on-topic.

Comment: @Ross, I don't know why they closed it! The easiest answer is that it is not supported like "noun" and "emph". you need to change the font manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't rally know about LyX, but in LaTeX there are the `lstlisting` (from the `listings` package) and the `verbatim` environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you search for `listing` on the lyx wiki homepage - you'll find [this](http://wiki.lyx.org/Examples/IncludeExternalProgramListing) - maybe it is of help to you.